# Potential System cost of a thread which waits 24 hours

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, power-management

In the application I'm writing, I want to take a backup of the data every 24 hours to help prevent the risk of data being lost in case of a file corruption or other failure.

To do this I am using a simple thread like this:

```
void BackupThread( const std::atomic<bool>& bTerminateFlag )
{
    std::stringstream ssFilePathAndName;

    while( !bTerminateFlag.load() )
    {
         std::this_thread::sleep_for( std::chrono::hours(24) );

         std::time_t std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t( std::chrono::system_clock::now() );

         ssFilePathAndName << "\\Backup" << "\\BackupFile-" << std::put_time( std::localtime( &t ), "%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S" ) << ".txt";

         // Save the data using our thread-safe Singleton object:
         g_pManager->Save( ssFilePathAndName.str() );

         ssFilePathAndName.str( "" );
         ssFilePathAndName.clear();
    }
}
```

I then start this using a reference to a member variable of my main application class:

```
m_backupThread = std::thread( BackupThread, std::cref( m_bBackupTerminateFlag ) );
```

However, I'm curious about whether this is a bad way (system-resource wise) to be going about this process, because although I have specified that the thread must wait 24 hours before waking, presumably the thread will be revived at various points by the scheduler/OS to check the time condition, and I was concerned about whether this would result in a non-negligible amount of power or CPU time being wasted (considering this will be running on the system constantly for a very long time, and it will not be the only process running on the system).

Comment: Seems silly.  Why not just set up a cron job (or a Windows `at` command) to run your program?

Comment: @JohnDibling - cron jobs, and other out-of-process schedulers, are not at all convenient for many tasks. If you want to flush data and close the files before copying, for example, it's usually a pain to get notification that the job is ready etc.  The thread is often just easier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sleep() is, typically, an extra entry in an ordered delta-queue in the kernel, so a minimal extra pointer has to be maintained in the container - the cost is indeed negligible.  There is no need to give the thread any CPU at all while it is sleeping.  That said, such long-delay operations are usually implemented by scheduled tasks or timers, but there's not much in it, overall.

Edit - also easy to test.  Write a trivial app that starts 5000 threads that do nothing except Sleep(24 hrs).  Run it, check its CPU use.  It will be 0.